# pip hangs when installing pandas after Download on RPi 3b/Raspbian

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am trying to install Pandas on my Raspberry Pi 3b inside a VENV. However everytime I do this, after the download pip hangs:

```
(venv) rene@raspberrypi:~/traq $ pip --no-cache-dir install pandas
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/ad/5e92ba493eff96055a23b0a1323a9a803af71ec859ae3243ced86fcbd0a4/pandas-0.23.4.tar.gz (10.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 10.5MB 5.3MB/s
```

Before I tried to install Dash, which worked without a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: How long does it hang for? Generally installing packages such as pandas on a rpi takes a long time due to the compilation and low powered cpu. If i recall correctly I had to wait for 10-15 minutes for it to complete the last time I did it.

Comment: Waited 10 minutes..Any way to make pip show more information, so that I can see that it is still doing something?

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3532

Comment: Just fire up a new terminal while it's installing and look at the CPU usage. If it's stuck at 100%, then you're good, just wait.

Comment: Thanks! It really took such a long time :D